# Utilizing PHP Explode is not dumping out parsed string

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a database where I am storing a long string in one column.  I am using two different delimiters.  I am using $$ to separate the 4 inputs user can input.  I am using ** to separate between each time the user enters the inputs (keep up with historical).  I am pulling the data and trying to display it within my php file.  Here is a portion of my code.  My code is working when no ** delimiter is found (only $$ is found).  However, when I enter the if statement due to finding **, my code quits printing data out.  I get no errors just a blank section on my page.  Do I have something set wrong in the while ($lUB < $bSize){} portion?

```
if ($userData[$index] != "")
 {
    if (strpos($userData[$index], '**') != false)
    {
     echo "here 0";
        $userDataB = explode("**", $userData[$index]);
        $lUB = 0;
        $bSize = count($userDataB);
        while ($lUB < $bSize)
        {
           $dataparse = explode("$$", $userDataB[$lUB]);
           echo ("<tr>");
           echo("<td>");
           echo  $dataparse[1];
           echo("</td>");
           echo("<td>");
           echo $dataparse[2];
           echo("</td>");
           echo("<td>");
           echo $dataparse[0];
           echo("</td>");
          echo("</tr>");
          unset($dataparse);
           $lUB = $lUB+1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
     echo "here 1";
        $dataparse = explode("$$", $userData[$index]);
        echo ("<tr>");
        echo("<td>");
        echo  $dataparse[1];
        echo("</td>");
        echo("<td>");
        echo $dataparse[2];
        echo("</td>");
        echo("<td>");
        echo $dataparse[0];
        echo("</td>");
       echo("</tr>");

    }
 }
 else
 {
    echo "here 2";
 }
```

Comment: Check the error log. A blank screen is usually a fatal error. Check if the status code is 500. Also `echo` isn't a function so it doesn't require the `()` and it can be concatenated. e.g. `echo ("<tr>");
                                   echo("<td>");` can just be `echo "<tr><td>";`. The `explode("$$"` may cause issues because of the double quotes, single quotes won't attempt to expand and will process minimally faster.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`


please use this to see errors on page.

and i would recommend that you add to your database, for each time a user will do something, one new row this will make your life easier, and besides that at some point your string will be very large and that will slow down your system/server

Answer (score 0):

If string is at the start of another string, strpos will return 0, which is equal to false in an if block, either you should use === operator or try to use some other function.